# Why writing new Runnable in the new Thread?

Tags: java, android

Can anyone please explain why one writes new Runnable in the new Thread? Fist time I saw this at android developers, please see the code in the link below.
Also, could you tell why we need to implement notifications in separate thread?

http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

I used to create threads by new Thread or with Runnable but not together, so got a bit confused..

Comment: _"Can anyone please explain why one writes new Runnable in the new Thread?"_ See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 2):

we can create a thread in two ways

> by extending Thread class and by implementing Runnable interface

if we create a class by extending Thread class like below

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread{
public void run(){
//job of a thread
}
public static void main (String[] args){
ThreadDemo d = new ThreadDemo();
d.start();
}
}
```

you can directly call `start()` and `jvm` internally calls `run()` method so that you can define job of Thread in `run()` by overriding it in your class.
But if you create Thread by implementing `Runnable(I)` like below.

```
class ThreadDemo implements Runnable{
public void run(){
//job of Thread 
}
public static void main(String[] args){
ThreadDemo d = new ThreadDemo(); //d.start() is not possible
Thread t = new Thread(d);//where d is target runnable
t.start()
}
}
```

you cant call `start()` directly with `ThreadDemo` instance because `Runnable(I)` contains only `run()` method, so you have to pass your `ThreadDemo` instance to `Thread` instance at the time of `Thread` creation it initializes your `target Runnable instance` and calls `Runnable` `run()` method not `Thread` class `run()` method.

```
new Thread(
    new Runnable() {
       ......
       .....
 }
    }
).start();
```

which is similar to

```
ThreadDemo d = new ThreadDemo(); //d.start() is not possible
    Thread t = new Thread(d);//where d is target runnable
    t.start()
```

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This is an just a lazy example that whoever set up that page wrote. Likely because it needed to be condensed and short.

All it's showing is how you display progress in the notification bar. What it's trying to tell you is that you can show progress in the notification bar during lengthy background operations.  It's thread safe and it doesn't have to be main UI thread, so feel free to display progress wherever you need it. Usually you don't use `Thread.sleep` during an operation while incrementing a counter.  In reality, to show the progress, you have to decide what the progress value represents during the course of the operation.

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood the question?  Did you want to know why you show progress in a thread or why you would use a Runnable instead of overriding `run()`?

Comment: So, we basically implement notification in a separate thread in order not to block UI thread?

Comment: @Rachael It's not going to block the UI thread.  It's showing that you don't have to run it on the UI thread. This is important since progress is (usually) shown for background operations that don't run on the UI thread.  You can show the notification on any thread that makes logical sense.

Comment: DeeV , just for final clarification, so what will happen if I don't write notification in a separate thread? I assume it will run on UI thread and so what will be the impact visually, will notification appear on my current activity screen?

Comment: @Rachael  It will run on the UI thread and it will appear in the system notification bar. This example only shows how to show progress in the system notification bar. This is completely separate from the Activity. If you want to show progress in your Activity, then you can put a ProgressBar somewhere in your View and add progress to that.

Comment: DeeV, thank you very much. I wonder if you've seen my other question, it seems like you can help me with that too, please refer to following link, if interested )
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396743/setresult-by-implicit-intent-does-not-work

Answer (score 1):

`Thread`s are java objects that represent threads of execution. `Runnable` is an interface for objects that represent some code intended to be executed by `Thread`s. Two concepts, two types (execution->`Thread`, code->`Runnable`).

For simplicity (?) `Thread`s are also `Runnable`s, so that in simple cases you just have to subclass `Thread` and override its `run` method (default implementation of `run` method does nothing). If you don't give a `Runnable` to a `Thread`, then it uses itself as the `Runnable` to execute.